# Aggregate Over Array of JSONB Efficiently

Tags: postgresql

I've got a table that stores a JSONB field (`data`) that contains Facebook like data. The data structure is:

```
-
id         | 9403
kind       | 'likes'
data       | [{ id: "1", name: "Pluto", category: "Planet"}, { id: "2", name: "Saturn", category: "Planet" }]
-
id         | 9403
kind       | 'likes'
data       | [{ id: "2", name: "Neptune", category: "Planet"}, { id: "3", name: "Mars", category: "Planet" }]
```

The goal is to write  query that aggregates by category the top N (5) likes per category. I've got the following subquery that I'm not sure how to optimize (with indexes or by re-writting). The goal is to get the grouping of counts for names and categories so they can be ranked. I'm starting with the simpler problem of efficiently selecting the N most popular:

```
SELECT
likes.entry->>'name' AS name,
likes.entry->>'category' AS category, 
COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(metadata.data::JSON) AS entry FROM metadata WHERE metadata.kind = 'likes') AS likes
GROUP BY name, category
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

That query already takes over 5 seconds to run (pasted explain / analyze):

```
Limit  (cost=39971.07..39971.07 rows=5 width=32) (actual time=5468.952..5468.954 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=39971.07..39971.17 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=5468.952..5468.954 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(*))
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=39969.61..39970.41 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=5241.143..5376.502 rows=392515 loops=1)
              Group Key: (likes.entry ->> 'name'::text), (likes.entry ->> 'category'::text)
              ->  Subquery Scan on likes  (cost=0.00..34491.46 rows=3652100 width=32) (actual time=0.104..4552.531 rows=880073 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on metadata  (cost=0.00..19883.06 rows=3652100 width=703) (actual time=0.097..2146.678 rows=880073 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((kind)::text = 'likes'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 90145
```

Can I somehow refactor this to be faster / add some indexes without using a materialized view? I tried adding the following (useless) index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_metadata_on_likes_raw ON metadata USING gin(data) WHERE (kind = 'likes');
CREATE INDEX index_metadata_on_likes_targeted ON metadata ((data ->> 'name'), (data ->> 'category')) WHERE (kind = 'likes');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you try:

```
select name, category, COUNT(*) AS count from(
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements(test.data::JSONB)->>'name' as name, jsonb_array_elements(test.data::JSONB)->>'category' as category FROM test WHERE test.kind = 'likes') a 
GROUP BY name, category
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```